# Failing to Update/Delete record in Sqlite from IOS App

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm creating an iPhone App which uses Sqlite to persist data,While i do **insert/select operations the code works fine**,but for **update /delete operations code gets failed**.
I found some links n stacker flow reg the same and some how **i fixed SQLITE_BUSY Error using BEGIN Transaction and Commit statements surrounded my update/delete statements**.Now if I execute he Update/delete statements,it returns **SQLITE_OK :0 : Successful results**.Also embedding the code here.I request the developers to please let me know where i went wrong.
For **testing purpose I hardcoded the values like 
"update drug set drugdose='2' where drugid=1".** 
After exe the statement it returns SQLITE_OK,but if I check the Database, the values are not getting updated.
enclosing two approaches i followed.

```
(BOOL )updateDrugDetails:(DrugDetails *)drugDetails{
BOOL *status=TRUE;
NSString *databasePath;
sqlite3 *database ;
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
sqlite3_stmt    *updateStatement;
BOOL statusUpdate;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
                [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"drugdb2.sqlite"]];
BOOL isSuccess = YES;
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSLog(@"databasePath %@",databasePath);
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
{

    NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
    isSuccess = NO;

}
else
{
    isSuccess = YES;
    NSLog(@"Able to open/create database");
}
if(isSuccess)
{
  NSInteger drugID= [drugDetails drugId];
  NSString *drugDose= [drugDetails drugDose];
  NSString *drugStartDate= [drugDetails drugStartDate];
  NSString *drugEndDate= [drugDetails drugEndDate];
  const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    NSString *temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", drugID];
    int tempInt=[temp integerValue];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
       /*
            // First Approach
        *updateSQL =
        [NSString stringWithFormat: 
        @"update drug set drugdose=?,drugstartdate=? ,drugenddate=? 
        where drugid =?"];

        const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
        const char *drgDose = [drugDose UTF8String];
        const char *drgStartDate = [drugStartDate UTF8String];
        const char *drgEndDate= [drugEndDate UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt,-1, &updateStatement, NULL);
        //  sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 4, [name.text UTF8String],
        -1,     SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStatement, 1, drgDose,-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStatement, 2, drgStartDate,-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStatement, 3, drgEndDate,-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int(updateStatement, 4, tempInt);

        sqlite3_busy_timeout(database, -1);
        int updtStatus;
        updtStatus=sqlite3_step(updateStatement);
        if (updtStatus == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Drug Details Updated with Status and rem Count");
            statusUpdate= YES;
        }else 
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to Update Drug Deatils with Status 
            rem Count%d",updtStatus);
            statusUpdate= NO;
        }
        if(statusUpdate==TRUE)
        {
            NSLog(@"drug updated");
            status=TRUE;
           // sqlite3_reset(updateStatement);
            sqlite3_finalize(updateStatement);
            sqlite3_close(database);
            database=nil;
            databasePath=nil;
            updateStatement=nil;
            databasePath =nil;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %d", statusUpdate);
            status=FALSE;
           // sqlite3_reset(updateStatement);
            sqlite3_finalize(updateStatement);
            sqlite3_close(database);
            database=nil;
            databasePath=nil;
            updateStatement=nil;
            databasePath =nil;
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(updateStatement);

        sqlite3_close(database);
    */
```

// Second Approach ,Inspite of hardcoding the values for testing purpose,its not updating //in DB.

```
    NSString *replaceStatement =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update drug set 
      drugdose='2',drugstartdate='10/10/10',drugenddate='10/10/10' where drugid=1"];
       char *error;
        int updateStatus;
       // sqlite3_busy_timeout(database, -1);
        NSString *begTxn=@"BEGIN TRANSACTION;";
         NSString *commit=@"COMMIT;";
        sqlite3_exec(database,[begTxn UTF8String],NULL,NULL,&error);

        updateStatus= sqlite3_exec(database, 
          [replaceStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error);
        // Here the updatStatus returns 0 ,i.e sqlite Success Operatiion

        sqlite3_exec(database,[commit UTF8String],NULL,NULL,&error);

        if ((updateStatus == 0))
        {
            NSLog(@"Drug Details  updated");
            sqlite3_close(database);
         }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error while Updating Drug Details %s", error);
            sqlite3_close(database);

        }

}

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to Open Dtabase");
        status=FALSE;
    }
}else 
{
   NSLog(@"Failed to get the DB Path");
   status=FALSE;
}
 return status;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to single-step through your code and check the variables are in the state you'd expect?

Comment: Yes ,the line **sqlite3_exec(database,[begTxn UTF8String],NULL,NULL,&error);:--> returns 0 ** **sqlite3_exec(database, 
          [replaceStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error)**:--> **returns 0**,**But** the commit statement i.e **sqlite3_exec(database,[commit UTF8String],NULL,NULL,&error); return 5**,which is **database locked**...